Error 400 When Publishing NuGet Packages to Azure Artifacts: Unable to load the service index for source
Description:
I am encountering an error while trying to publish NuGet packages to an Azure Artifacts feed using an Azure DevOps pipeline. The error message I am receiving is as follows:
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<<organization>>/<<feed>>/nuget/v3/index.json.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

Context:
The YAML pipeline configuration is as follows:
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  packageVersion: '1.0.$(Build.BuildId)'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '8.x'

- script: |
    dotnet restore
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'

- script: |
    dotnet build --configuration Release
  displayName: 'Build project'

- script: |
    dotnet pack --configuration Release --version-suffix $(packageVersion) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  displayName: 'Create NuGet package'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    publishVstsFeed: 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<<organization>>/<<feed>>/nuget/v3/index.json'
    apiKey: '$(System.AccessToken)'
  displayName: 'Push NuGet package to Azure Artifacts'

Problem:
The error indicates that the request to the NuGet feed returned a 400 (Bad Request) status code, with the message:
Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<<organization>>/<<feed>>/nuget/v3/index.json.
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

Question:
How can I resolve this authorization error and successfully publish my NuGet packages? Are there additional checks or configurations that I should review to fix this issue?
Thank you in advance for your help!
I configured a YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps to restore, build, pack, and publish NuGet packages to an Azure Artifacts feed. I expected the NuGetCommand@2 task to successfully push the package to the feed without errors. However, the process fails with a 400 Bad Request error, indicating issues with loading the service index for the specified feed URL.

I could reproduce the 400 error based on your pipeline definition, which didn't seem to use the properties of the NuGetCommand@2 task correctly.

Here is my working nuget push step for your reference.
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    publishVstsFeed: 'OrgScopeFeed-NuGet' # Use the organizational feed name directly
    # apiKey: '$(System.AccessToken)' # apiKey is not a valid property 
  displayName: 'Push NuGet package to Azure Artifacts'



Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was doing wrong. In fact, I had included the entire link, but instead, you just need to put something like this: 'publishVstsFeed: /'. And the advice to remove 'apiKey' was correct.
I am infinitely grateful to you

Anytime and happy to know my sample nuget push step can resolve your issue in this post. Please feel welcome to post new queries and we are always willing to help. Good luck with the work to go. cheers. ^_^
